# What sizes to use for a 4x2 appwidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I'm trying to create an appwidget that has a standard size of 4x2 tiles.
Currently, I'm using these values:

```
android:minHeight="146dp"
android:minWidth="294dp"
```

On my Desire running Gingerbread, the widget shows as 4x2.
On my Asus TF101 tablet running ICS, the widget gets a size of 4x2.
Finally, in an emulator 720x1280 running ICS, the widget gets a size of 4x3.

So I'm a bit confused here. What are the correct values (perhaps using different resource folders) to achieve a 4x2 widget on all devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that working on approx. 72dp x 72dp per 1x1 works best.  So for a 2x2 widget I would normally use 144dp x 144dp, however google recommends 110dp x 110dp.

This page from Google gives a better description of what size to use and how to calculate it:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

Comment: This solution does not work on 7'' tablets. Checked on the Nexus 7 2013 and the widget size is 3x2 cells and horizontally cropped. On smartphones like the OnePlus One it is 4x2 cells and looks ok. Set to **280 dp** worked, now the cell sizes are 4x2 on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

According to google guidelines you should use this formula : 70 × n − 30

For a 4*2 widget that means you should use 250dp * 110dp.

More infos : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html